# Azure AD B2C Signout response message

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

how to change signed out response message on azureADB2C or how to remove the response message on azure ad2bc after successful signout

Find below screenshot
[Default Signout message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWBvO.png)

Answer (score 0):

The B2C logout endpoint redirects you back to the application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request

Is this what you implemented? The image appears to be a logout from Azure AD, not AAD B2C. The cropping of the url makes it hard to tell.